# Collapsible left-side tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, twitter-bootstrap

I was wondering if there is a better way to write the following code? The code is working, I am looking for better technique to achieve the functionality, if any exists. Never mind the classes that are not shown, indentation, class names, etc. I am focused mostly on the functionality.

[JsFilddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ekareem/tsnmrv12/59/)

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
   <li>
        <a href="#ulExpCol_1" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-link="#item_1" onclick="$('#thisCollapsedChevron_1').toggleClass('fa-rotate-90')">
                             <i class="zz_TreeParent" id="thisCollapsedChevron_1"></i>
                    Top Tree Node
            </a>
            <ul id="ulExpCol_1" class="ml-3 list-unstyled collapse">
                    <li>
                            <a href="#ulExpCol_2" data-toggle="collapse"
                            data-link="#item_1-1" onclick="$('#thisCollapsedChevron_2').toggleClass('fa-rotate-90')">
                            <i class="zz_TreeParent" id="thisCollapsedChevron_2"></i>
                            Child 1
                            </a>
                            <!--Child 1 -->
                            <ul id="ulExpCol_2" class="ml-3 list-unstyled collapse">
                            <li>
                                    <a href="#item_1-1-1" class="zz_TreeLeaf">
                                            Child 1.1
                                    </a>
                            </li>
                    </ul></li> 
            </ul></li> 
            <li>
            <a href="#item_2" class="zz_TreeLeaf">
                    Last Node
            </a>
            </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! (The `Enhance code` part of the title is somewhat implicit here.) `Never mind [some aspects of the code]. I am focused [on one particular one]` OK as far as you respect [any aspect of the code posted being fair game for feedback and criticism](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @greybeard, I appreciate the comment.